# System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsApplication1.exe Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am writing a very basic database input form for a sql database using vb.net

upon executing the code

```
dsnewrow = ds.Tables("Car Details").NewRow()
```

i am declaring dsnewrow just before this in the same sub here:

```
 Dim dsnewrow As DataRow
```

and ds is being declared here:

```
Dim ds As DataSet
```

in the public class of the form.

I understand that there is a problem with my ds variable, but I don't understand what it is,can anyone help?

full program:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Form1
    Dim inc As Integer
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim maxrows As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
        Dim cb As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)

        If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure that you want to delete this record?", _
                           "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, _
                           MessageBoxIcon.Warning) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then
            MsgBox("Operation Cancelled")
        Else
            ds.Tables("Car Details").Rows(inc).Delete()
            maxrows = maxrows - 1
            inc = 0
            NavigateRecords()
            da.Update(ds, "authors2")
        End If

    End Sub

    Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Car_DetailsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CourseworkDataSet.Car_Details)
        Dim sqlstring As String
        Dim conn As SqlConnection
        Dim connstring As String


        connstring = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Coursework.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"

        conn = New SqlConnection(connstring)
        conn.Open()
        MsgBox("successful")

        sqlstring = "SELECT * FROM Car Details"
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlstring, conn)
        ds = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "Car Details")

        conn.Close()
        conn = Nothing

        maxrows = ds.Tables("Car Details").Rows.Count
        inc = 0
        navigaterecords()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Car_DetailsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Car_DetailsBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.Car_DetailsBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.CourseworkDataSet)

    End Sub

    Private Sub NavigateRecords()
        MakeTextBox.Text = ds.Tables("Car Details").Rows(inc).Item(0)
        ModelTextBox.Text = ds.Tables("Car Details").Rows(inc).Item(1)
        Engine_SizeTextBox.Text = ds.Tables("Car Details").Rows(inc).Item(2)
        ColourTextBox.Text = ds.Tables("Car Details").Rows(inc).Item(3)
        DoorsTextBox.Text = ds.Tables("Car Details").Rows(inc).Item(4)
        Buy_PriceTextBox.Text = ds.Tables("Car Details").Rows(inc).Item(5)
        Sell_PriceTextBox = ds.Tables("Car Details").Rows(inc).Item(6)

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnFwd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFwd.Click
        If inc <> maxrows - 1 Then
            inc = inc + 1
            NavigateRecords()
        Else
            MsgBox("No More Records")

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click
        If inc > 0 Then
            inc = inc - 1
            NavigateRecords()
        Else
            MsgBox("First Record")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnFirst_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFirst.Click
        If inc <> 0 Then
            inc = 0
            NavigateRecords()
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnLast_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLast.Click
        If inc <> maxrows - 1 Then
            inc = maxrows - 1
            NavigateRecords()

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
        Dim cb As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
        ds.Tables("Car Details").Rows(inc).Item(0) = MakeTextBox.Text
        ds.Tables("Car Details").Rows(inc).Item(1) = ModelTextBox.Text
        ds.Tables("Car Details").Rows(inc).Item(2) = Engine_SizeTextBox.Text
        ds.Tables("Car Details").Rows(inc).Item(3) = ColourTextBox.Text
        ds.Tables("Car Details").Rows(inc).Item(4) = DoorsTextBox.Text
        ds.Tables("Car Details").Rows(inc).Item(5) = Buy_PriceTextBox.Text
        ds.Tables("Car Details").Rows(inc).Item(6) = Sell_PriceTextBox.Text

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        btnUpdate.Enabled = False
        btnAdd.Enabled = False
        btnConfirm.Enabled = True
        btnDelete.Enabled = False

        ModelTextBox.Clear()
        MakeTextBox.Clear()
        Engine_SizeTextBox.Clear()
        ColourTextBox.Clear()
        DoorsTextBox.Clear()
        Buy_PriceTextBox.Clear()
        Sell_PriceTextBox.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnConfirm_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConfirm.Click
        If inc <> -1 Then
            Dim cb As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
            Dim dsnewrow As DataRow

            dsnewrow = ds.Tables("Car Details").NewRow()

            dsnewrow.Item("Make") = MakeTextBox.Text
            dsnewrow.Item("Model") = ModelTextBox.Text
            dsnewrow.Item("Engine Size") = Engine_SizeTextBox.Text
            dsnewrow.Item("Colour") = ColourTextBox.Text
            dsnewrow.Item("Doors") = DoorsTextBox.Text
            dsnewrow.Item("Buy Price") = Buy_PriceTextBox.Text
            dsnewrow.Item("Sell Price") = Sell_PriceTextBox.Text

            btnConfirm.Enabled = False
            btnAdd.Enabled = True
            btnUpdate.Enabled = True
            btnDelete.Enabled = True

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        btnUpdate.Enabled = True
        btnAdd.Enabled = True
        btnConfirm.Enabled = True
        btnDelete.Enabled = True
        inc = 0
        NavigateRecords()
    End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: can you show more of your code please?

Comment: `Dim ds As new DataSet`

Comment: Can post the error message you get?

Comment: the error is the title of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only declaring the variable ds. You should create an instance, before you can use the methods.

```
Dim ds As DataSet
```

should be

```
Dim ds As New DataSet
```

or

```
Dim ds As DataSet
ds = New DataSet
```

Answer (score 2):

This line in Form_Load is wrong

```
sqlstring = "SELECT * FROM Car Details"
```

A table name when contains spaces should be enclosed in square brackets

```
sqlstring = "SELECT * FROM [Car Details]"
```

when you execute the query it doesn't work and your dataset is never initialized with new. Then when you try to use it you get the NULL Reference Exception. I suppose that you run this code on a 64bit system where [the exceptions in a Form_Load event are ignored](http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/07/20/the-case-of-the-disappearing-onload-exception-user-mode-callback-exceptions-in-x64/)

Comment: Correcting that still returns the same error, but thank you for picking up on that, clearly I need to read more around my lecture material!

Comment: It fails on the same line?

Comment: yeah, exactly the same place

Comment: I suggest to put a breakpoint in that line and when hit, hover with your cursor on the variable ds to see if it is null, Check also if you have a table named Car Details in your dataset

Comment: ds is [system.data.dataset]. I have a table calld Car Details in the Data Connections panel,and I have the table present in the data set.